# React - using deep equality as to not re-render on object identity change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

React discusses on [this page about performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html) that you can use shallow equality and avoid mutating objects, so that components need only to check references to see if props or state changed.

I'm actually wondering about the opposite: is it possible to have the equality check use deep equality and ignore when the object references change (as long as their contents don't change)?

Reason is, I have a library which returns a cloned version of some internal variables, and to see updates on those variables, I need to re-ask for that internal variable, thus getting a fresh new clone. So I'll get entirely different objects by reference, but they could have not changed any of their fields. But every time I request such an update, React thinks everything has changed because all the references changed, and it re-renders a lot of unnecessary stuff.

Current solution: threw this in a component to stop it from rendering as long as the objects' *fields* don't change

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return !_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !_.isEqual(this.state, nextState);
}
```

which does the trick since lodash's `isEqual` equality check is deep, but I'd have to do that on each component that wants this behavior. I wonder if there's either a

- preferred way of achieving this
- an anti-pattern I'm using which leads to this in the first place and I could avoid it entirely

or maybe the above method is best.

Comment: If you wanted this as the default behavior for a set of components, perhaps you could extend `React.Component` and override `shouldComponentUpdate` as such.  So perhaps have something like `class DeepEqualityComponent extends React.Component`, then extend from `DeepEqualityComponent`

Answer (score 2):

I would not suggest you do this for the following reasons:

1. Deep comparisons are costly. So everytime something changes you will have to do a deep comparison and then do the rendering part. We would just be better off letting react do the rendering cause it was made for it.
2. As for the case of handling it in all the components. We can avoid this problem by destructuring the object thus sending smaller props, now the react can handle the optimised re-renders. eg:

   `<Footer data={object} />`

   `<Footer title={object.title} copyright={object.copyright}/>`

I hope that helps!